# Selenium How to check the drop down list item is selected

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static WebElement drpdwn_selectMonth() throws Exception{
    try{
        WebElement monthSelector = driver.findElement(By.id("monthID"));
        monthSelector.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        monthSelector = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='monthID']/option[2]"));
        monthSelector.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }catch (Exception e){
        throw(e);
    }
    return element;
}
```

1. how to do a Boolean check there is a value under drop down list is selected?
2. how to print and get the value selected in drop down list

Comment: If you can share the HTML snippet, that will be helpful. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think no need to check selected boolean , because it will print value only if It can select.

Comment: provide a sample html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your given little details , It can be done in below way :

```
WebElement monthSelector = driver.findElement(By.id("monthID"));
monthSelector.click();

if(monthSelector.isSelected())

   {

       Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("monthID")));
       sel.selectByVisibleText("Your-dropdown-value");


   }
 else

   {
        System.out.println("Sorry , Dropdown not selected yet");


    }
```

Please replace **Your-dropdown-value** with your dropdown actual value e.g "January".

Better you also share your HTML code , if above does not work for you.

Comment: thanks for your code suggestion, but it not work. month is just a sample. my drop down list value is integer (eg. 20012) which are dynamic value. My intention are select one of the value, and verify there is an item selected.

Comment: it values comes dynamic then use xpath please.

Comment: using 'monthSelector.isSelected()' is working. thanks @Helping Hands

Answer (score 1):

HTML snip would help, but here's my take.  If your menu element is a `<select>` element, you can make use of the [Select API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html).

Once instantiated with your WebElement representing the root locator of the menu, you can use the `getAllSelectedOptions()` or `getFirstSelectedOption()` methods to retrieve the text of the selected option(s).  From here, you can print the value, or validate the selected option in your assert statement.

This is only high level concept, but if you read through the API Doc, you should be able to come up with the solution that fits your needs.